# Add XSLT validation on XSLT File Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, validation, xslt

I have a Rails application with Paperclip file upload which is used to upload a XSLT file. I am looking for ways to validate the XSLT file before uploading. i can actually validate the content_type using paperclip

```
  validates_attachment_content_type :xslt, content_type: "application/xslt+xml", message: 'Invalid Content Type. Please upload a valid XSLT file'
```

Is there a way I validate the XSLT file completely for syntax before saving it?

Comment: Depends what you are looking to validate about it. XSD's or DTD are normally used for validating XML based files (XSLT's being an XML based file)

Comment: OTOH, xslt can contain arbitrary xml snippets so a specific validation may be hard. You'd have to have more information on what you consider "valid" than what is specified in the question. Might be easier if the output method would have to be text.

Comment: The output would be an HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Oxygen Editor to validate it or you can write the .net tool to validate it using **Saxon** dll.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the xslt files you could use the Nokogiri gem and do it as follows:

```
validate :xslt_validation

def xslt_validation(xml_message)
  xml = Nokogiri::XML(xml_message)
  template = Nokogiri::XSLT(File.open(Rails.root.join('path from root to xslt')))
  validation = template.transform(xml)
  result = Hash.from_xml(validation.to_s)['Name of the error report']

  errors.add(:xslt_field, "XSLT errors: #{result['Errors']}") if result['Errors'].present?
end
```